# Rails 3 - 2 projects on localhost suddenly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, localhost, webrick

I would need to have run 2 projects in Rails (v. 3) on my localhost. I use WEBrick - is it possible?

In this time I have to switch among 2 or 3 projects my server and it's a bit uncomfortable - so - it's possible to work on more projects with WEBrick suddenly?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple ports. The first instance, you can run on, say 80. The second, you run on 81.
You can open one tab with `localhost:80` (or just `localhost`), and another tab with `localhost:81` in your browser.

(If you're using ports below 1000 or so on a Mac, you need to have administrator rights: use `sudo`.)

Comment: Damn, sorry for the stupid question... I forgot on parameter `p`. For the others - `sudo rails -s -p80`.
Thank you **Tim**!